# IIS8 permissions on mapped network drive in domain

Tags: .net, iis, permissions

On my PC (Windows 8) I logon as a domain user, there is no local user on my PC. I installed IIS8, Visual Studio 2012 etc to develop .NET webapplications.

I have setup IIS with default settings; .NET v4.5 DefaultAppPool with ApplicationPoolIdentity as identity.

My projects are on V:, which is a mapped network drive. I setup a website pointing to V:\Website1, when opening this website I receive the error:

```
HTTP 500 Cannot read configuration file; \\?\V:\Website1\web.config
```

Which user needs read permissions for V:\Website1 directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the user: IIS AppPool\[AppPoolName]

See this link: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: In your link: 6.Click the "Locations" button and make sure you select your machine. -> I can only select DOMAIN.local here. Also DefaultAppPool check name has no result. The commandline works, but still I get the same error.

Comment: Is this machine a domain controller?  The only time you should not be able to select the local machine is on a domain controller, and in that case the domain would be what you want.  Did you enter "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" (assuming the app pool in question is the default app pool)?

Comment: No it's not a domain controller. Yes, I added the user like you mention, in the security tab this user (DefaultAppPool) also shows up with the correct permissions. But still IIS is throwing the error. Is there some property which stops IIS from reading from a mapped network drive perhaps?

Comment: None that I am aware of.  You must be adding the user from the local machine context, it wouldn't exist in the domain.  Alternatively, you can go the app pool advanced settings, and change the user that it runs as to either a specific user or something like NETWORK USER that might work better for you.

Comment: It is very strange. I have set the AppPool identity to the domain user I also logon with to my PC. I am 100% sure this user can access the files and the path is correct, but still the "Cannot read configuration file" error. In the Test connection window in IIS basic settings for website, with this user it says Authorization: The path does not exist or environment variables in the path could not be expanded to verify whether it exists.

Comment: I just discovered this; if I specify the application path as \\server-name\Website1\ it works! If I specify the mapped drive as V:\Website1\ it does not work. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Because a mapped drive is an "environment" specific configuration.  Meaning the mapped drive is a service that windows explorer is providing to you when you are logged in.  For example, if you configured a windows service (which is what an IIS worker process really is) to run as your local user, it also wouldn't have access to that mapped drive.  Hopefully that makes sense. Here's a KB article that has some more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257174

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll just use the network path, because no matter what use I give read rights to the mapped drive it just wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using unc path?
http://forums.iis.net/t/1189399.aspx